# Ruby Nokogiri Parsing Multiple Elements within Lists

Tags: ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

```
<div class='prdlist'>
 <ul>
  <li class='first'>
   <a href="some url 1">
    <div class="text>
     <br>product number 1
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class='second'>
   <a href="some url 2">
    <div class="text">
     <br>product number 2
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Using above example,

I would like to parse the values inside each list, list by list. Something like:

```
html.xpath("//*[@class='prdlist']/ul/li'").each do |each|
 url = each.xpath/css (parse the href from each list)
 name = each.xpath/css (parse the text from each list)
end
arr << [url,name]
```

which would eventually output:

```
arr = [["some url 1","product number1"],["some url2","product number2"]]
```

I am currently using regex & xpath("//*[@href]/@href) to get all urls and similar to get all product names and then using .zip to put the arrays together... but I've come across an html where I would like to do it list by list..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

And there you have it.

```
arr = []

html.css("div.prdlist li").each do |me|
    url  = me.css("a").map{|link| link['href']}[0]

    name = me.text.delete("\n").split.join(" ")
    arr << [url,name]

end
```